# Read in from a textdata and show it in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qtableview, model-view

I dont know ..
I would have a textdata for example:

> Name, Value
>
> Hans, 13
>
> Peter,30

I dont know how i read it in .. Can anyone help me a little bit ?

```
QString fileName;
fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Datei Oeffnen"),"",
                                            "Alle Dateien (*.txt)");
//QString in QFile
    QFile file (fileName);

//Status ob File gelesen werden kann

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("ERROR"), tr("Daten konnten icht eingelesen werden"));
    return;
}
QTextStream stream (&file);
       
while (!file.atEnd())
{
      QString line = stream.readLine();
      QStringList list = line.split(",");
      //dont know, because i woult have 2 Strings. because i would add it in my 
      // Model  : meinModel->setData(firstString,secondString);

}
```

This is my Model's `setData` method:

```
bool Model::setData(QString name,QString value )
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), names.size(), names.size());
    names.push_back(name);
    values.push_back(value);
    endInsertRows();
    qDebug() << "inhalt name:"<< name;
    qDebug() << "inhalt value:"<< name;

    std::cout << names.size() << std::endl;
    QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0,0);
    QModelIndex bottomRights = createIndex(names.size()-1,1);
     //emit a signal to make the view reread identified data
    emit dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRights);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should do like this `meinModel->setData(list.at( 0 ), list.at( 1 ) );` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is very difficult solution, I done this easier. My code snippet works as you want, also in comment I show you your mistakes.

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);


QString fileName;
//QString in QFile
    QFile fileMy ("G:\\2\\fil.txt");

if (!fileMy.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("ERROR"), tr("Daten konnten icht eingelesen werden"));
    return;
}
QTextStream stream (&fileMy);

int conterX = 0;
while (!stream.atEnd())//your error was here, you should use stream, not a file
{
      QString line = stream.readLine();
      QStringList list = line.split(",");

      QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem(list.first());//first name
      model->setItem(conterX,0,item1);
      QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem(list.last());//last name
      model->setItem(conterX,1,item2);
      conterX++;

}
ui->tableView->setModel(model);//setmodel
```

My file:

```
Hans,13
Peter,30
Foo,15
Bar,20
Baz,25
```

Result on picture

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer, but i have a view.cpp and a model.cpp. i don't need a QStandartItem. I need 2 Strings . i dont set the Strings in my view.cpp , because i have a model with a setdataMethode... How can i put it in strings ?  it has to fit into : meinModel->setData(firstString,secondString);

Comment: can i I can simply replace QStandardItem with QString ? and in each step i can call setdata only once..

Answer (score 0):

can i make it so ?

```
while (!stream.atEnd())
{
      QString line = stream.readLine();
      QStringList list = line.split(",");
      QString firststring;
      firststring = (list.first());
      QString secondstring;
      secondstring = (list.last());
      QString *secondstring = new QString(list.last()); 
      meinModel->setData(firststring, secondstring);

          }
```

Comment: QString *secondstring = new QString(list.last()); I think you don't need this. Is this works as you want?

Comment: I'm glad that it is works. Now can you vote up my main answer and mark it as accepted? http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: i'am to new 2 vote. "vote up requires 15 reputation "